# how to resize dialog which are added to property sheet?

Tags: mfc

i am trying to rezize dailog which are added to property sheet using move window function but nothing is affecting. it taking same size as in resource file.
how to resize it in code ?

Answer (score 0):

this->MoveWindow(xPosInScreen, yPosInScreen, Width, Height);

You can use it on initialisation function.

Comment: in oninitdialog() i am trying to call this->MoveWindow(xPosInScreen, yPosInScreen, Width, Height); but its not effecting at all . what would be the reason

Comment: Do you added the function within UpdateData(true); UpdateData(false); segment? It can be an issue.

Comment: use actual numbers, 200, 200, 400, 400.

Comment: used actual value didn't get the result

Comment: Try this http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Source_Code/Visual-C-Sample-Resize-dialog-Resize-Property-Sheet-Resize-Property-Page-CPropertySheet-CPropertyPage.htm